# PHP Curl get data

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm created a simple PHP curl client that call a external webservice. This webservice return the XML.

```
<?php
// Method: POST, PUT, GET etc
// Data: array("param" => "value") ==> index.php?param=value
function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }
    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
$response = CallAPI('GET','https://s1-en.ogame.gameforge.com/api/universes.xml');
var_dump($response);
//print string(1121) " "
?>
```

But it always gives me back the wrong value. I print `string(1121) " "`.

How can I get the call data? (line 41 in the `test.php`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are viewing the result in browser and the browser parses the xml as valid html tag. So you get empty result.

Its not your code issue. you can press `ctrl + u` (view source) in browser to see the actual result.

Or you can edit your `var_dump` to `echo htmlentities($response);` on line 41.